# Подключение локальной БД из файла на С++

Tags: c++, sql

Пытаюсь подключиться к базе данных, созданной через Visual Studio (Средства -> Подключиться к базе данных).

Файл с базой имеет формат .mdf

Чтобы пользоваться классом CDatabase библиотеки MFC, нужно подключиться к базе через Панель задач -> Администрирование.

Но почему-то локальный сервер не доступен для подключения.

Подскажите, что не так? И как вообще можно подключиться и работать с локальной БД через С++. Может быть есть способ проще. С# не предлагать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну так а локальный сервер у вас запущен?

Comment: да, сервер запущен

Comment: SQLite возможно будет проще

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Подключение к базе данных на C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/998161/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c)